# Cannot send sms on phonegap - doesnt have permission

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I cant send SMS messages on my app. The goal is to send the messages without using the native SMS messaging application on the phone. But everytime I try sending, it just said it failed. Here is the code I used.

```
function reqPermission() {
    //get permissions for sending SMS
    var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
    permissions.requestPermission("android.permission.SEND_SMS", sendSMS, requestError);
}

function sendSMS(){
    alert("success requesting permission");
    //CONFIGURATION
    var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            //intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
            intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
        }
    };
    var number = document.getElementById('numberTxt').value.toString(); /* iOS: ensure number is actually a string */
    var message = document.getElementById('messageTxt').value;
    console.log("number=" + number + ", message= " + message);
    //send SMS
    var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
}
function requestError(){
    alert("failed to set permissions");
}
```

I have added the plugin, "cordova-plugin-android-permissions" version 1.0.2 to the config.xml file. I also did the following.

added permission

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" source="npm" spec="~1.0.0" />
```

, on the following locations:

- config.xml

added

```
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

on following locations:

- \platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- \platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml
- \config.xml

added this block of code to
\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml

```
    <feature name="Permissions">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.android.plugins.Permissions" />
    </feature>
```

edited minsdkvalue on package files from value 14, changed to 16:

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

added

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

on files:

- \platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- \plugins\cordova-sms-plugin\config.xml
- \config.xml - under platform name, android

I followed steps following these sources:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W47ZJ1vgqqI
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sms-plugin

I also used hasPermission function to verify if I have the right permission for the SEND_SMS feature, it doesnt return true or false, it just returned an Object. I test all of this on my phone.

my version of Android package on the PC is 7.0.0, version of cordova is 8, my phone android version is 9. Ill also note that everytime the app is initially installed on the phone, it doesn't say to have permissions for sending SMS messages.

Can someone point me to the right direction here? I am pretty sure it has something to do with permissions. Thank you.

Comment: No success yet.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't. I just asked the proffesor if its possible that phonegap just opens the messenger app, and we can just send the message manually.. He agreed so I didn't bother solving this problem anymore. And I think this will require us to ask for authorization from google first. Sorry for the late update.